# Когда используется REVOKE TO?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В официальной [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) указано, что `REVOKE` можно выполнять не только с `FROM`, но и с `TO`. Можно ли так сделать на практике, и в чем отличие?

Можно ли выполнить, например

```
REVOKE INSERT ON table TO ivan1337 CASCADE
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` и `TO` для `REVOKE` являются синонимами, функциональной разницы между ними нет.

В [грамматике](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2011-foundation-grammar.html#_12_access_control) SQL-стандарта для `GRANT` определено `TO`, а для `REVOKE` - `FROM`. Таким образом `REVOKE ... TO ...` в T-SQL является расширением грамматики стандарта (или, если угодно, отклонением). Точно так же как, например, `FOR` и `AFTER` для триггеров (`AFTER` - стандарт, `FOR` - расширение).

Хотите быть ближе к стандарту - используйте `FROM`. Если в этом нет необходимости - используйте то, что больше нравится (что-то одно, как правило).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, я то думал, что TO и FROM имеют абсолютно противоположное назначение)